# C# / Dot.Net Framework automatic user interface

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface

All end-user program has an user interface that in a lot of cases is the replication of a code Class.
Is there a tool/library that can do a direct end user parameter interfaces like the one of visual studio to set prop of a object?

[image: Visual studio prop panels]

Ex:

```
class Animals
{
    string Nome;
    AnimalType type;
}
```

[image: stupid Animal Exampe]

Obviously that need additional parameters like order and constraints.. and also an output like a panel or a form...

Comment: That would be [PropertyGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid(v=vs.110).aspx), but there's a reason it's rarely used, even though it's available since 2003. Only developers tolerate such UIs. Users *hate* them

Comment: Most container controls in Windows Forms, WPF, ASP.NET allow you to specify templated for items. Since 2008 (I think) that includes templates for specific types, from top level entities all the way down to built-in types. It's quite common in WPF, especially when using an MVVM framework like Caliburn.Micro, to define separate views for viewmodels that get composed by the framework to create the final screen

Comment: Which stack are you targetting? WinForms (tough), WPF, ASP.NET Webforms, ASP.NET MVC ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WPF is the good solution, but as https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos said...

> users really, really hate property grids

Answer (score 0):

Telerik has a really useful property grid in the WPF controls library which I used with great results, not for free though...

[Telerik Property Grid](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/propertygrid.aspx)

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments, users really, really hate property grids. That includes developers when working outside an IDE. That's why they are rarely used even though they are available since 2003. Generic UIs can be composed using templates, especially in WPF

Comment: Thanks, but i was looking for a poor programmer solution.

Comment: @StefanoCucchi for which platform? Do you *really* want Visual Studio's property grid as your application's UI? A composable UI is a lot easier to do in WPF or ASP.NET MVC - templating or views per type are built-in

Comment: I agree, usually users does not love these implementations. But on the other hand, sometimes this is what's needed, there was no mention about what kind of end user the application was targeting.